# Save different data into different csv files

Tags: python

When I use this program to read all the cryptocurrencies, it will save all of them into one file only. How can I save different coins  data into different csv file? 
Please help me, thankyou very much.

```
def CoinNames():
    """Gets ID's of all coins on cmc"""

    names = []
    response = requests.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0")
    respJSON = json.loads(response.text)
    for i in respJSON:
        names.append(i['id'])
    return names

def gather(startdate, enddate, names):
    historicaldata = []
    counter = 1

    if len(names) == 0:
        names = CoinNames()

    for coin in names:
        sleep(10)
        r  = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/{0}/historical-data/?start={1}&end={2}".format(coin, startdate, enddate))
        data = r.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
        table = soup.find('table', attrs={ "class" : "table"})

        #Add table header to list
        if len(historicaldata) == 0:
            headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
            headers.insert(0, "Coin")

        for row in table.find_all('tr'):
            currentrow = [val.text for val in row.find_all('td')]
            if(len(currentrow) != 0):
                currentrow.insert(0, coin)
            historicaldata.append(currentrow)

        print("Coin Counter -> " + str(counter), end='\r')
        counter += 1
    return headers, historicaldata

def _gather(startdate, enddate):
    """ Scrape data off cmc"""

    if(len(sys.argv) == 3):
        names = CoinNames()
    else:
        names = [sys.argv[3]]

    headers, historicaldata = gather(startdate, enddate, names)

    Save(headers, historicaldata)

def Save(headers, rows):

    if(len(sys.argv) == 3):
        FILE_NAME = "HistoricalCoinData.csv"
    else:
        FILE_NAME = sys.argv[3] + ".csv"

    with open(FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(headers)
        writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
    print("Finished!")
```

Comment: What code have you tried to split it with? It looks like you could use an element (such as coin type?), and add that into your data; if so, you could use that as a discriminator in your Save() function to store to separate files based on coin type.

Comment: Hi Steve, I think you can do this without our help. You're nearly there. I'm betting that when you run this code, you have a single file `HistoricalCoinData.csv` and instead you want something like `HistoricalData-BTC.csv`, `HistoricalData-ETH.csv`, etc. Now, think: do you have access to the coin abbreviations, like BTC, ETH, etc? You'll need these if you want your filenames to be dynamic. Next, think: How can you use these abbreviations to save the csv files with dynamic file names? Good luck!

Comment: Yea I know I have to separate but I have never wrote python before. What I have to do now is to type the full name of each coin one by one in order to get one coin per file. Or download one file that consist of 100 coins. I want to run this program in one click and all the coins are separated. Can someone tell me some key words in python? Thankyou

Comment: If you are a beginner in Python you should start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)